# Передача неизменяемого контейнера в качестве параметра метода

Tags: java, c++

Нужно передать в качестве параметра контейнер, который не должен быть изменен в этом методе, причем его элементы тоже не должны быть изменены.

В `c++` это выглядит как-то так:

```
void doSomething(std::vector<SomeClass> const & vec)
{ /* do something */ }
```

Как такое сделать в `Java`? У меня есть предположение, что это может быть как-то так, но я до конца не понимаю, как в данном случае сработает `final` - сделает ли он так же неизменяемыми элементы контейнера, а не только сам объект контейнера:

```
public static void doSomething(final List<SomeClass> list)
{ /* do something */ }
```

Собственно, вопрос в том, прав ли я в том, как это сделать. Если нет, то как надо? Если да, то какие вообще существуют правила работы `final` в параметрах методов?

Comment: Используйте `Collections.unmodifiableCollection` для `List<SomeClass>`, а для `SomeClass` финальные поля.

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь что в Java так вообще не выйдет написать. final только гарантирует что list не будет изменен, а его содержимое может меняться(это чем-то напоминает константный указатель, указатель изменить нельзя, а содержимое можно).

Comment: `Боюсь что в Java так вообще не выйдет написать` -- вполне себе получится.

Answer (score 1):

Для коллекций делайте `Collections.unmodifiable***` (там есть враперы для всех основных типов). А вообще - пишите свой врапер-обертку, который будет оборачивать ваш класс и кидать эксепшен на "изменяющие методы", но проксировать "читающие". Соответственно, для максимально удобной работы с такой схемой, объект и врапер к нему должны наследовать единый общий интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

Может так пойдет?

```
public List<SomeClass> replaceList(final List<SomeClass> input) {
    List<SomeClass> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final SomeClass sc : list)
        output.add(sc);
}
```

Comment: Задача больше состоит в самопроверке - метод не должен в принципе изменять исходную коллекцию (и желательно, чтобы это запрещалось на этапе компиляции). Вдобавок, скорее всего, коллекция будет достаточно большой, чтобы ее копирование было неприемлемо

Comment: а как насчет зафиналить все в SomeClass?